# Which elements of ${\bf Z}$ are definable without parameters in ${\bf Z}$?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Consider ${\bf Z}$ as a first-order structure in the language $(0, +, -)$ of Abelian groups.

Which elements of ${\bf Z}$ are definable without parameters?

I think only 0 is, because there is no way to distinguish between x and -x.

Comment: You are of course correct. The mapping $x \mapsto -x$ is an automorphism of $\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: @user414998 You should just post that as an answer . . .